# .net technology that must be learned

Tags: .net

Our company is offering some trainings and asks us what would we want to learn. We are using .net technologies so it will be .net platforms.

my thoughts are wcf, asp.net mvc 2.0, silverlight, .net 4.0 platform. Which of these? you can add on the list.

thanks

Comment: that is a very general question. It would be helpful to mention the size of the company. (in terms of number of teams, developers, number of existing software developed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can get training on OO, and design patterns, Test Driven Development (TDD) and Domain Driven Design (DDD). Topics like this are technology independent and will help you improve your general coding skill and deliver better code.

As for what .Net technologies you need to learn this depends on the applications you plan to implement. Without knowing exactly what you'll be implementing I'd recommend that you learn a language C# or VB.Net well, as other technologies such as sliverlight entity framework etc will build on your language skills.

Also you mention web technologies therefore Azure could potentially be of interest to your company, my own knowledge of this is limited at the moment but if you develop sites that have traffic that peaks at certain times Azure might be worth considering.

Again as you mention so many web related technologies I would make sure and learn CSS and jQuery, again these are platform independent allowing you to take these to any platform in the future.

Comment: Indeed, TDD and design patterns are more important. I would include Integration tests (like Fitnesse).

Answer (score 3):

I think you should also consider F# and functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

Redundant. .NET 4.0 platform includes all the rest.

What language?

I would go with:

C#
WPF
WCF
ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

I would add NHibernate to the list.

Answer (score 0):

A .net Companu Should Use and aware of

1. Nant
2. NUnit
3. Team Foundation Server
4. WPF (silverlight)
5. WCF
6. .net 4.0
7. Asp.net MVC
8. in-house Framework
9. EntityFramework / NHibernate
10. Linq